# WooCommerce : Hide add to card when price is 0 or 1

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I'm currently using the product table plugin which works very well, but I have a question about it. Actually, my customers need to create an account to see prices on my website. Sometimes, products are unavailable so customers are able to ask for a quotation. Here's a capture:

Unfortunately, it's working only when the user is non-logged. [image: Screenshot showing LIRE LA SUITE button]

Can I replace the "Read more" button (LIRE LA SUITE in french) with an ADD TO QUOTE button?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests and/or recommendations are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow, we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). 
Tell us what you have tried so far and then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );

function woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text( $add_to_cart_text, $class ) {
    if ( 'Read more' == $add_to_cart_text || 'LIRE LA SUITE' == $add_to_cart_text ) {
        return __( 'ADD TO QUOTE', 'woocommerce' );
    }
}
```

Add this to your active theme functions.php file.